# How do I inject JavaScript into a JPG image and execute it when uploaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, injection

I've recently joined a security project, and received a task to demonstrate the risk related to an end-user uploading an image containing embedded (malicious) JavaScript code.

I used [EXIFeditor](http://exifeditor.software.informer.com/) to inject JavaScript code in an image's `imgdescription` tag, then uploaded the image to the ASP.NET web server using the following C# code:

```
protected void Upload_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var postedFile = Upload_fu.PostedFile;
    string fileName=new FileInfo(postedFile.FileName).Name;
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fileName);
    postedFile.SaveAs(path);
    Success_msg.Text = "successfully saved";
    img_sr.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fileName;
}
```

**Note:** `img_sr` is a `<asp:Image/>` element, and `Upload_fu` is a `<asp:UploadFile/>` element.

The JavaScript code I've embedded int the image is a simple `alert("Hello world")`. However, the code isn't executed (I tried this with FireFox 21 and Internet Explorer 9).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One way to exploit the wrong content sniffing implementation of old MSIE. Another way to serve the exif information along the image without escaping HTML.

Comment: can u explain more please

Comment: Use google, it is really not hard to find...

Comment: You might try this method: http://www.wikihow.com/Hide-Text-Within-an-Image You can hide the js inside the actual jpg

Answer (score 1):

Create a HTML page where you display the photo, and next to it you display the EXIF info. The EXIF javascript should probably be enclosed in HTML script tags. If you don't escape the EXIF info when you display it in the page, it should execute the javascript.